# Error while flattening the IQueryable<T> after GroupBy()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am trying to get flattened object from the database, but I get an error. I want to get 2 books for all genres in the database, the code looks like this:

```cs
IQueryable<Book> query = _context.Books
                                 .GroupBy(b => b.Genre)
                                 .SelectMany(bc => bc.Select(b => b).Take(2));
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong in here?

I get this exception instead of a result :

> The LINQ expression '`bc => bc .AsQueryable() .Select(b => b) .Take(2)`' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I tried also something like that :

```
IQueryable<Book> query = _context.Genres.GroupJoin(
     _context.Books,
     g => g,
     b => b.Genre,
     (g, books) => new
     {
         Genre = g,
         BookCollection = books
     }
    ).SelectMany(bc => bc.BookCollection.Select(b => b)
    .Take(2)).Include(b => b.Author).Include(b => b.Rating)
             .Include(b => b.BookISBNs).Include(b => b.Reviews)
             .ThenInclude(r => r.User);
```

Comment: It might help if you tell us what you think you're doing wrong (or why you think you're doing something wrong).

Comment: What do you expect your query to return?

Comment: Yes, of course, It gives me exception instead of result :
The LINQ expression 'bc => bc
    .AsQueryable()
    .Select(b => b)
    .Take(2)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: I expect it to return the IQueyrable of Book objects.

Comment: If it gives you exception, always include the error message in the post.

Comment: EF fails to translate the code to a DB query. You need to use a method that will force the Query to execute before using `SelectMany` on the result. Try `....GroupBy(b => b.Genre).ToList().SelectMany(...)`

Comment: @Marta "_I expect it return the IQueyrable of Book objects._" - `_context.Books.AsQueryable()` will also give you an `IQueryable<Book>`. But you don't really want that. Please, state clearly (in the post) what result you are expecting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This attempt moves away from group by, which is restrictive in the database and EF query translation. Instead, we're going for a subquery.

```
var genres = _context.Books.Select(b => b.Genre).Distinct();
var books =
  from genre in genres
  from book in _context.Books.Where(b => b.Genre == genre).Take(2)
  select book;

var results = books.ToArrayAsync();
```

Aiming for this kind of translation:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT Genre FROM Books) as a,
  (SELECT top 2 b.* FROM Books b WHERE b.Genre = a.Genre) as c
```

Comment: It would actually help me out quite a bit if you test this and it works. I would link back to here from https://stackoverflow.com/a/491832/8155

Answer (score 1):

So, you want to group the `Book` entities by `Genre`, and then get a flat list of books containing two books from each group. I don't think you can express that with a `LINQ` query using `GroupBy()` which Entity Framework can translate to SQL.

But its not EF's fault or shortcoming. `GROUP BY` in SQL is restricted to return only the grouping key(s) and/or any aggregation performed on the group. For example, you can group the books by `Genre`, and then want the genre and total number of books per group -

```cs
var result = dbCtx.Books
    .GroupBy(p => p.Genre)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Genre = g.Key,       // grouping key
        Count = g.Count()    // aggregation on group
    })
    .ToList();
```

EF can generate SQL for that -

```sql
SELECT [b].[Genre] AS [Key], COUNT(*) AS [Count]
FROM [Books] AS [b]
GROUP BY [b].[Genre]
```

This reference might help - [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby)

> Since no database structure can represent an IGrouping, GroupBy
> operators have no translation in most cases. When an aggregate
> operator is applied to each group, which returns a scalar, it can be
> translated to SQL GROUP BY in relational databases. The SQL GROUP BY
> is restrictive too. It requires you to group only by scalar values.
> The projection can only contain grouping key columns or any aggregate
> applied over a column.

Therefore, for your query, you have to fetch the books and do the grouping on the client side, like -

```cs
var result = dbCtx.Books.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(p => p.Genre)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(book => book).Take(2).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: But I want to return result as return await result.ToArrayAsync() in the method Task<Book[]> so it is not workinkg like that, and the second problem is that i need to join to it records from other tables containing book id as FK, like BookIsbn, revievs, and so on. I understand that i can do it by include, but then only for one specific genre.

Comment: @Marta I have updated the answer and the query for flat list. So, try the updated query. Simply replace the `ToList()` with `ToArrayAsync()` to get a `Book[]` with an async call. If you have any other issues, please consider posting new questions for them.