# Get only rows with the latest date for each name

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, .net-5

I'm trying to write a query that returns only those rows that contain the latest date for each name.

So for example, this data:

| Name | Date Sold | More Columns... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 2021-01-05 |  |
| Mike | 2021-01-18 |  |
| Susan | 2021-01-23 |  |
| Bob | 2021-02-04 |  |
| Susan | 2021-02-16 |  |
| Mike | 2021-03-02 |  |

Would produce this result:

| Name | Date Sold | More Columns... |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | 2021-02-04 |  |
| Susan | 2021-02-16 |  |
| Mike | 2021-03-02 |  |

It's sort of like a `GROUP BY`, but I'm not aggregating anything. I only want to filter the original rows.

How could I write such a query?

*NOTE: In the end, this will be a SQL Server query but I need to write it using Entity Framework.*

**UPDATE:** In reality, this is part of a much more complex query. It would be extremely difficult for me to implement this as a raw SQL query. If at all possible, I need to implement using Entity Framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get top 1 row of each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group)

Comment: @SMor: Looks similar but I don't think that approach is even possible in Entity Framework.

Comment: Perhaps place the row-numbering in a view, then select from that in EF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from
[Error while flattening the IQueryable<T> after GroupBy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66526675/error-while-flattening-the-iqueryablet-after-groupby/66529949#66529949)

```
var names = _context.Items.Select(row => row.Name).Distinct();
var items =
  from name in names
  from item in _context.Items
    .Where(row => row.Name == name)
    .OrderByDescending(row => row.DateSold)
    .Take(1)
  select item;

var results = items.ToArrayAsync();
```

---

Let's break this down:

A query expression which establishes the keys for our next query. Will eventually be run as a subquery.

```
var names = _context.Items.Select(row => row.Name).Distinct();
```

Another query, starting with the keys...

```
var items =
  from name in names
```

... and for each key, let's find the matching row ...

```
  from item in _context.Items
    .Where(row => row.Name == name)
    .OrderByDescending(row => row.DateSold)
    .Take(1)
```

... and we want that row.

```
  select item;
```

Run the combined query.

```
var results = items.ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: I'm going to need to reread that a few dozen times until it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Two options

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable 
 Order by row_number() over (partition by Name order by Sold_Date desc)
```

or slightly more performant

```
with cte as (
Select *
      ,RN = row_number() over (partition by Name order by Sold_Date desc)
 From  YourTable
)
Select *
 From  cte 
 Where RN=1
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is `ties *` in your first example? Also, do I assume you're a SQL Server guy, and not an Entity Framework guy?

Comment: @JonathanWood You are correct... skipped right over the EF.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
;with Groups as
(
    Select [Name], max([Date Sold]) as [Date Sold]
    From Table
    Group By [Name]
)
Select Table.* From Groups
Inner Join Table on Table.[Name] = Groups.Name And Table.[Date Sold] = Groups.[Date Sold]
```

Comment: But, as explained, I will need all columns in the row.

Comment: oh I see now, I will change my answer soon @JonathanWood

Comment: @JonathanWood I edit my answer now you can get all columns with that filter